# Docker Volume contents not copied to Container

Tags: docker

I have a local  volume created in docker

when i run the following command the content inside volumes  as successfully copied to the docker container

```
docker run -d \
  --name devtest \
  --mount source=mydata,target=/var/www/admin/public \
   local:5000/api-live/php-fpm:2021-04-22-07.19.24
```

However when i try to do the same in docker-compose the contents dont get copied just the Destination folder is created

```
services:

  fpm:
    image: local:5000/api-live/php-fpm:2021-04-22-07.19.24
    ports:
      - "9090:9000"
     volumes:
       - ./mydata:/var/www/admin/public
    restart: always
```

Thanks in advance for helping

Comment: Have you tried append a trailing slash on both paths: `./mydata/:/var/www/bomann/admin/public/` ?

Comment: Hey Xavier, Thank you for the reply . Yes i have tried with trailing slash on both paths:

Comment: your targets is different, one is `/var/www/admin/public`, and the other is `/var/www/bomann/admin/public`

Comment: hey @frank_lee i have corrected this. Still same issue :-)

Comment: Do you create the folder `mydata` before `docker-compose up` ?

Comment: Yes The mydata volume was created too before docker-compose https://puu.sh/HAtlw/ee22818cef.png

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When the *volume* has been already created, *which is deduced through the first `docker` command with bind `--mount` switch*, you have to specify such a state to *docker compose* in order for the latter to not create a new volume named after your project name (*[project_name]_mydata*.

This can be achieved using the `external: true` volume property:

```
services:
  fpm:
    image: local:5000/api-live/php-fpm:2021-04-22-07.19.24
    ports:
      - "9090:9000"
     volumes:
       - mydata:/var/www/admin/public
    restart: always
  volumes:
    mydata:
      external: true
```